# How to duplicate rows in a numpy array based on a value in each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want duplicate rows in `numpy` arrays based on the numeric value of the first entry in each row. So if the value is 1, then the row isn't duplicated, but if the value is 3 that row will be represented 3 times. I tried to use `np.repeat` and `np.tile` but I don't know if they're the right tool for this and I haven't figured out if there is a way to do it yet.

Here are my randomly generated arrays :

```
[[[3 1 3 1 2]
  [4 4 4 2 0]
  [3 4 4 4 0]
  [1 4 3 3 0]]

 [[4 2 0 2 1]
  [2 1 2 0 3]
  [4 1 3 4 3]
  [2 3 2 0 0]]]
```

My goal is to end up with this:

```
[[[3 1 3 1 2]
  [3 1 3 1 2]
  [3 1 3 1 2]
  [4 4 4 2 0]
  [4 4 4 2 0]
  [4 4 4 2 0]
  [4 4 4 2 0]
  [3 4 4 4 0]
  [3 4 4 4 0]
  [3 4 4 4 0]
  [1 4 3 3 0]]

 [[4 2 0 2 1]
  [4 2 0 2 1]
  [4 2 0 2 1]
  [4 2 0 2 1]
  [2 1 2 0 3]
  [2 1 2 0 3]
  [4 1 3 4 3]
  [4 1 3 4 3]
  [4 1 3 4 3]
  [4 1 3 4 3]
  [2 3 2 0 0]
  [2 3 2 0 0]]]
```

Here is the code I have so far

```
array = np.random.randint(5, size = (2, 4,5))

for a in array:
    for b in a:
        array = np.tile(a, (b[0],1))
```

If I print `b[0]`, I can get each value. I want to use those values to duplicate each row.

```
3
4
3
1
4
2
4
2
```

So I thought I could loop through those values and multiply each row by its corresponding value to add new rows, but my result only duplicates the second array one time.

```
[[4 2 0 2 1]
 [2 1 2 0 3]
 [4 1 3 4 3]
 [2 3 2 0 0]
 [4 2 0 2 1]
 [2 1 2 0 3]
 [4 1 3 4 3]
 [2 3 2 0 0]]
```

Where am I going wrong? Should I not use `np.tile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no guarantee that your original 2D sub-arrays in the 3D source array will have the same shape after performing this operation, they cannot in general be stacked back into a 3D array.

You can get a `list` of arrays with `np.repeat` by passing the first column of each 2D array as the number of repeats. It will then repeat each row the corresponding number of times:

```
from pprint import pprint

result = ([np.repeat(a[i], a[i, :, 0], axis=0) for i in range(a.shape[0])])

pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
[array([[3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
       [3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
       [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
       [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
       [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
       [1, 4, 3, 3, 0]]),
 array([[4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 0, 3],
       [2, 1, 2, 0, 3],
       [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
       [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
       [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
       [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
       [2, 3, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 3, 2, 0, 0]])]
```

Comment: Thanks @gmds your solution works great. I was just wonder, if the arrays were whole number floats instead of ints could I pass the 0th row in as ints to repeat the rows?

Comment: @oaktree If they're definitely whole numbers, then you don't need to modify anything. However, if you want to be safe, you can change the repeat parameter to `a[i, :, 0].astype(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.repeat` with `np.arange`:

```
import numpy as np

    arr = np.array([[[3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
  [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
  [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
  [1, 4, 3, 3, 0]],
 [[4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [2, 1, 2, 0, 3],
  [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
  [2, 3, 2, 0, 0]]])

arr2d = np.vstack(arr)
dup = arr2d[np.repeat(np.arange(arr2d.shape[0]), arr2d[:,0])]
np.split(dup, np.cumsum(np.sum(np.split(arr2d[:,0], arr.shape[0]), 1)))[:-1]
```

Output:

```
[array([[3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
        [3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
        [3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
        [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
        [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
        [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
        [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
        [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
        [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
        [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
        [1, 4, 3, 3, 0]]), 
 array([[4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
        [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
        [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
        [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
        [2, 1, 2, 0, 3],
        [2, 1, 2, 0, 3],
        [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
        [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
        [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
        [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
        [2, 3, 2, 0, 0],
        [2, 3, 2, 0, 0]])]
```

Since the 2d-arrays do not always have same shape, most of the time it will yield list of arrays. Such inconsistency is not so well handled by `numpy`.

In such case, you can simply use `itertools.repeat` with `list` comprehension. (Though it looks quite similar to @gmds' answer)

Given `l`:

```
import itertools

l = [[[3, 1, 3, 1, 2], [4, 4, 4, 2, 0], [3, 4, 4, 4, 0], [1, 4, 3, 3, 0]],
 [[4, 2, 0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 2, 0, 3], [4, 1, 3, 4, 3], [2, 3, 2, 0, 0]]]

[[j for i in sub for j in itertools.repeat(i, i[0])] for sub in l]
```

Output:

```
[[[3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
  [3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
  [3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
  [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
  [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
  [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
  [4, 4, 4, 2, 0],
  [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
  [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
  [3, 4, 4, 4, 0],
  [1, 4, 3, 3, 0]],
 [[4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [4, 2, 0, 2, 1],
  [2, 1, 2, 0, 3],
  [2, 1, 2, 0, 3],
  [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
  [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
  [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
  [4, 1, 3, 4, 3],
  [2, 3, 2, 0, 0],
  [2, 3, 2, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: I got something like this too, but how do you handle the 3D case?

Comment: It's not possible to handle the 3D case in the sense that the results cannot generally be stacked back into a single array, since they might have different shapes in the 1st dimension.

Comment: @gmds yes indeed. I tried to make the solution as general as possible but it is still quite messy :p Feel like this question is not something numpy is good at

Comment: @Chris since you don't think numpy is good at this what do you think would be better to use?